# How to use sinon to stub aws-param-store getParametersByPath()

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, sinon, aws-parameter-store

I'm using the package aws-param-store and I'm trying to write Unit tests
that stub calls to getParametersByPath().
Package can be found here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-param-store

Here is my sinon code to stub the call. The function getParametersByPath is an async function
so I'm trying to return a resolved promise to stub it:

```
const awsParameterStore = require('aws-param-store');
const sinon = require("sinon");
let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

// In My Test:
let parms = new Map();
parms.set("key1","value1");
parms.set("key2","value2");  

sandbox.stub(awsParameterStore,'getParametersByPath').callsFake(async function(prefix){
    console.log("INSIDE STUB for getParametersByPath:" + prefix);       
    return Promise.resolve(parms);
});
```

My app makes a call to the function like this:

```
let parameters = await awsParameterStore.getParametersByPath("/foo");
```

However, instead of getting back the Map of dummy parameters, I get an empty object {}.
I can see that the stub is getting called.
Any ideas on how to properly stub this so I can return some dummy parameters in my unit tests?
Thanks!

Comment: If you replace `parms` in your function with a static value, like `34`, does that value make it to your caller? If so, you may be overwriting `parms` before your method is called.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to check your code, and it's completely fine.

```
import test from 'ava'

const awsParameterStore = require('aws-param-store');

const sinon = require('sinon')

test('test stub', async t => {
    let parms = new Map();
    parms.set("key1","value1");
    parms.set("key2","value2");
    parms.set("key3","value3");
    parms.set("key4","value4");

    sinon.stub(awsParameterStore, 'getParametersByPath').callsFake(async function(prefix){
        console.log("INSIDE STUB for getParametersByPath:" + prefix)
        return Promise.resolve(parms);
    })

    const res = await awsParameterStore.getParametersByPath('/some-prefix')

    console.log(JSON.stringify(res))

    res.forEach((value, key) => {
        console.log(`[${key}]= ${value}`)
    })

    t.true(true)
})
```

What is weir:

> console.log - show that result is {}

but if you debug or log the value one by one, you can see that *stub* works fine:

```
Debugger attached.
INSIDE STUB for getParametersByPath:/some-prefix
{}
[key1]= value1
[key2]= value2
[key3]= value3
[key4]= value4
  ✔ test stub
```

**UPD**: problem is how to log Map by *JSON.stringify()*. So, you must log the map as:

> console.log(JSON.stringify([...res]))

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const awsParameterStore = require('aws-param-store');

async function main() {
  let parameters = await awsParameterStore.getParametersByPath('/foo');
  return parameters;
}

module.exports = main;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const main = require('./');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const awsParameterStore = require('aws-param-store');
const { expect } = require('chai');
let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

describe('59787603', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    let parms = new Map();
    parms.set('key1', 'value1');
    parms.set('key2', 'value2');
    sandbox.stub(awsParameterStore, 'getParametersByPath').resolves(parms);

    const actual = await main();
    expect(actual).to.be.eql(parms);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
  59787603
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (11ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59787603